# Change include-ref in gitlab-ci.yml to master after merging?

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml

I have following code in a yaml file of a branch of repo

```
include:
   project: my-project
   ref: test_branch
   file: common.yml
```

Now after merging it with master how do I make the ref to point to master automatically as the common.yml is in the test_branch only as of now?

Comment: is it within the same project? or do you want to include from another project?

Comment: It is within the same project.

Comment: so to understand your problem: you are in your `test_branch` and modifying in there the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and after merge it should not point to the version within you branch but to the `common.yml` of the same branch?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is within the same repository and you want to access always the file within the same branch, you can also use

```
include:
  - local: common.yml
```